# Is there a way to sort NBA starting lineups together with the appropriate matchups into different tables?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, nba-api

how can i match the teams together that are versus eachother in the same rows and columns

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.rotowire.com/basketball/nba-lineups.php"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

lineups = soup.find_all(class_='is-pct-play-100')
positions = [x.find('div').text for x in lineups]
names = [x.find('a')['title'] for x in lineups]
teams = sum([[x.text] * 5 for x in soup.find_all(class_='lineup__abbr')], [])

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(names, teams, positions))
df.to_csv('team_lineups.csv', index=False)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
0   Damian Lillard  MIL  PG
1    Malik Beasley  MIL  SG
2      Jae Crowder  MIL  SF
3      Brook Lopez  MIL   C
4     Tyrese Maxey  MIL  PG
..             ...  ...  ..
92    James Harden  CHA  PG
93    Terance Mann  CHA  SG
94     Paul George  CHA  SF
95   Kawhi Leonard  POR  PF
96     Ivica Zubac  POR   C

[97 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Please update the question and add an example of the exact output you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.rotowire.com/basketball/nba-lineups.php"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

lineups = soup.find_all(class_='is-pct-play-100')
positions = [x.find('div').text for x in lineups]
names = [x.find('a')['title'] for x in lineups]
teams = sum([[x.text] * 5 for x in soup.find_all(class_='lineup__abbr')], [])

# Split the data into two separate DataFrames for each team
team1_df = pd.DataFrame(zip(names[:5], positions[:5]), columns=['Player', 'Position'])
team2_df = pd.DataFrame(zip(names[5:], positions[5:]), columns=['Player', 'Position'])

# Add team names as a column in each DataFrame
team1_df['Team'] = teams[0]
team2_df['Team'] = teams[5]

# Merge the two DataFrames to create the final matchup DataFrame
matchup_df = pd.merge(team1_df, team2_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('_Team1', '_Team2'))

# Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
matchup_df.to_csv('team_matchups.csv', index=False)

print(matchup_df)
```

Output:

```
     Player_Team1 Position_Team1 Team_Team1      Player_Team2 Position_Team2 Team_Team2
0  Damian Lillard             PG        MIL       Buddy Hield             SG        PHI
1   Malik Beasley             SG        MIL     Tobias Harris             SF        PHI
2     Jae Crowder             SF        MIL     Nicolas Batum             PF        PHI
3     Brook Lopez              C        MIL         Paul Reed              C        PHI
4    Tyrese Maxey             PG        MIL  D'Angelo Russell             PG        PHI
```

Comment: This is awesome! Basically what I was looking for you nailed it.

Comment: One more thing, how would I add every matchup from that day ? This code seems to be only importing  the first 2 teams. @TheHungryCub

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated version that add column `Match` (in what match the player figures) and `Team` (the player's team):

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.rotowire.com/basketball/nba-lineups.php"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

data = []
for lineup in soup.select(".lineup__box:has(.is-pct-play-100)"):
    v, h = (
        lineup.select_one(".lineup__team.is-visit").text.strip(),
        lineup.select_one(".lineup__team.is-home").text.strip(),
    )

    for l in lineup.select("ul.lineup__list .is-pct-play-100"):
        pos = l.div.text
        name = l.a.text
        team = l.find_previous("ul")["class"][-1]
        if team == "is-home":
            team = h
        else:
            team = v
        data.append({"Match": f"{v} - {h}", "Name": name, "Pos": pos, "Team": team})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.head(15))
```

Prints:

```
        Match           Name Pos Team
0   MIL - PHI     D. Lillard  PG  MIL
1   MIL - PHI  Malik Beasley  SG  MIL
2   MIL - PHI    Jae Crowder  SF  MIL
3   MIL - PHI    Brook Lopez   C  MIL
4   MIL - PHI   Tyrese Maxey  PG  PHI
5   MIL - PHI    Buddy Hield  SG  PHI
6   MIL - PHI  Tobias Harris  SF  PHI
7   MIL - PHI  Nicolas Batum  PF  PHI
8   MIL - PHI      Paul Reed   C  PHI
9   LAL - PHX     D. Russell  PG  LAL
10  LAL - PHX  Austin Reaves  SG  LAL
11  LAL - PHX  Rui Hachimura  PF  LAL
12  LAL - PHX   Devin Booker  PG  PHX
13  LAL - PHX  Grayson Allen  SF  PHX
14  LAL - PHX   Kevin Durant  PF  PHX
```